# Using FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON across the Android system

Tags: android, powermanager, android-powermanager

The goal of my app is to keep the screen on across the whole `Android` system. Previously, I've used [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK) for this and it allowed me to block dimming of the screen across  the system. However, since the API Level 17, it got deprecated:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Most applications should
>   use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will
>   be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between
>   applications and doesn't require a special permission.

[Official documentation recommends](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) using [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON), however it is possible to use it only for particular `Activity`.

I would still [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK), however I've found that it doesn't work now on some of the devices, like MediaPad Huawei x2, Redmi Note 3, etc. The way I'm currently using the `PowerManager` can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/yyunikov/android-dim-block/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yyunikov/dimblock/base/WakeLockManager.java#L46). Is there any better way to do accomplish this task after `API level 17`?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with API 23 and its new Doze mode Wake Locks are ignored and they do not prevent the system from entering sleep.

You should experiment with maintaining a foreground service in parallel with the wake lock, theoretically that should prevent the device from entering sleep.

**NOTE**: the foreground Service has to call startForeground and show a non dismissable Notification

Comment: I'm aware of `Doze` mode and keeping the background service is actually what I'm currently doing, but unfortunately this doesn't work on some of the devices. You can check my implementation here: https://github.com/yyunikov/android-dim-block/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yyunikov/dimblock/service/DimBlockService.java#L31

Comment: I added a Note, your Notificaction class should call builder.setOngoing(true); ... I think.

Comment: Just tried it - Foreground service alone won' keep screen from dimming out or going to sleep. Implementing wake lock in foreground service does prevent screen from going to sleep, but it still dimms.